# Creating the Name of the checkbox dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have just written this code and assign the name of the check box dynamically  and delete the selected checkbox when delete button is pressed. But it isn't working. Can somebody help me??

#### main.php

```html
$snooverhtml = "select * from songs_list";
$query7 = mysqli_query($con, $snooverhtml);?>
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
<input id="deletebtn" type="submit" name="deletethis" value="Delete"/></br> 


<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query7)):?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo "cb".$row['sno.'];?>"/><?php echo $row['sno.']?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $row['songs_name']?></br>
<?php

endwhile;

?>
```

#### delete.php

```html
$noofsongs = "select * from songs_list";
$query8 = mysqli_query($con, $noofsongs);
$noio = mysqli_num_rows($query8);
$flag = 0;
if(isset($_POST['deletethis'])){
for($j=0; $j<=$noio ;$j++){
 
 if (isset($_POST['<?php echo"cb".$j;?>'])){
 $deletesongsquery = "DELETE FROM `songs_list` WHERE `sno.` = $j" ;
 $query4 = mysqli_query($con, $deletesongsquery);
 
 $flag = $flag + 1;
 
   }    
 
 }
echo $flag;
 }
```

Comment: is main.php working? I mean the song names displays there now? or not working also?

Comment: Yeah main.php is working properly. and song name is displaying. But when I select the checkbox and press delete then it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already in PHP so `$_POST['<?php echo"cb".$j;?>']` is incorrect. That is looking for `<?php echo"cb".$j;?>` literally as an index of `$_POST` which it never finds so `isset` is false. Use:

```
$_POST['cb'.$j']
```

or in your code usage:

```
if (isset($_POST['cb'. $j])){
```

You also should use parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thank You So Much. It is now working. I am now wondering that why my attention was not directed in that way.